# Groovy - How to substitute elements in a string that were found with a regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm trying to create a generic solution for increasing a version number which regex is given as a parameter. The regex works well so far but the next part, which is returning the same syntax as the original one, is what drives me crazy right now.

The code snippet:

```
def increase(tag, regex, position){
    tag[position] = (tag[position] as Integer) + 1
    def newTag = tag[0].replaceAll(regex, ???)
    return newTag
}
```

So, if I give these parameters:

```
// entry params:
tag = ['1.0.RC119', 1, 0, 119 ]
regex = /^(\d+).(\d+).RC(\d+)/
position = 3
```

The result should be `1.0.RC120`

With these parameters:

```
tag = [ '1.0u2', 1, 0, 2 ]
regex = /^(\d+).(\d+)u(\d+)/
position = 3
```

The result should be `1.0u3`

What should I give to `replaceAll` as replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may split the string with 1+ digits and then interleave the resulting list with the `tag` items and joining to get the final string:

```
List combineList(List one, List two) {
    def result = [one, two].transpose()
    ( result += (one - result*.get(0)) ?: (two - result*.get(1)) ).flatten()
}

def increase(tag, regex, position){
    tag[position] = (tag[position] as Integer) + 1
    return combineList(tag[0].split(/\d+/), tag[1..-1]).join())
}
```

See a [Groovy demo online](https://ideone.com/yzkTFQ).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Wiktor, but building "${tag[1]}.${tag[2]}.RC${tag[3]}" implies that that the tag has always this structure, which it doesn't because it is given as a parameter.

Comment: @DavidPG The replacement pattern must always correspond to the regex, and the regex you have is `regex = /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.RC(\d+)/`. So, it is a valid solution. If it does not work, please add more details to the question and let know.

Comment: in the question I mentioned that the regex AND the tag are parameters, therefore I cannot use `"${tag[1]}.${tag[2]}.RC${tag[3]}"` inside the method. Nevertheless, I tried to clarify a bit more giving to examples of use.

Comment: thanks, @Wiktor! Though my solution works too, I prefer yours for not being messing around with many 'replace' methods.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, though I think it's a little "dirty":

```
def increase(tag, regex, position){
    tag[position] = tag[position] + 1
    def newTag = regex.toString().\
                       replace('^', '').\
                       replace('\$', '').\
                       replace('(d+)','@__@')
    tag[1..-1].each {
        newTag = newTag.replaceFirst('@__@', it.toString())
    }
    return newTag
}
```

Surely it won't cover all the cases, but will mostly work for me.